# how to dynamically scale the svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am little new to svg . i have svg that shows the map,map is formed using the path.

Now in my application user will submit the height and width of the map so i want to re-size the map to the same width and height how should i scale the svg?

this is my basic svg code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="721" height="650" viewBox="0 0 721 650" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="US" transform="translate(528,270)">

            <a id="s01">
                <path d="M158.95067408594068,46.88327098850149L185.03303599629845,44.0148159910488L189.74121811302572,59.50889743727097L196.59587401503094,82.27898337817625L199.0518321008348,87.17077847298319L201.13017099189912,89.85649424407167L200.707578706067,91.7588142001174L202.6261541288344,92.6205139503571L200.33524838576966,95.29216920133321L200.7363444144292,97.59217497211156L199.80999341478454,100.8918397716738L202.09021078470892,106.20782432993735L201.64399529140977,111.17790897235179L204.03767592952832,115.96122130827978L196.3574723373462,117.09985438789514L163.47293491613115,121.08122011183377L163.22294648718562,123.55296427740802L167.13791879442175,126.6835133291724L166.871741037497,129.76735843938286L168.2485001228969,131.1400084527912L166.21795234496457,134.1137855808483L164.12121282499038,134.9547500732084L159.81791064191435,132.36796011584426L158.90469329765804,127.88713803963412L157.64560372254968,127.51168600895127L156.5390262005875,131.08669596034315L156.36678872306632,134.46030822963786L152.20800610122825,133.97284127048096L148.16895577705603,105.98121856614907L148.12136132417422,70.56398790998259L148.15893441899317,50.102043132249676L146.40831263672231,48.33943105796875Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-dasharray="1, 0" stroke-width="1.5"/>
                <text x="162.66165594858754" y="86.92631614090374" style="">AL</text>
                <title/>
            </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can scale a SVG by using viewBox. This property accept 4 parameters, seperated with blanks, to describe a new coordinate system inside the SVG.

Set the viewBox to the origin coordinate system an set the width and the height of the SVG new, the way you want.

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');

var svgWidth = parseFloat(svg.getAttributeNS(null, "width"));
var svgHeight = parseFloat(svg.getAttributeNS(null, "height"));

function scaleSVG(percent)
{
    svg.setAttributeNS(null, "width", svgWidth * percent);
    svg.setAttributeNS(null, "height", svgHeight * percent);
    svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 " + svgWidth + " " + svgHeight);

}

scaleSVG(2);
```

**demo** https://codepen.io/martinwantke/pen/LQpPyB

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `<g id="US">` in another `<g>` with `transform="scale(0.1)"` (to scale to 1/10th the size for example)

Then you can modify this new `<g>`'s scale value dynamically

Comment: but how would i get the scale value dynamically as user is giving me height width.

Comment: Your initial width is 720. Say the user gives a width of 300. 300/720 would be around 0.4. Do the same for whatever height value the user gives (For this example, the resulting scale is also around 40%). Then your transform would look like `scale(0.4, 0.4)`

Comment: what about viewbox do i need to change its witdh or height too , i think other wise it will get croped

Comment: ^ That decision is on you as to what should happen when they resize it too big or too small. Only answering how to scale SVGs :D

Comment: Ok but i just want to ask how should i manage my view box in both the cases when i am resize big and when resize small. i know nothing about it to manage all i get it just crop my svg

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this, but with your own scale.

```
    }
function SVGscale(scale) {
    window.SVGsetDimension(640*scale,480*scale);
    window.SVGsetScale(scale,scale);    
        if (!W3CDOM) return;
    var box     = document.getElementById('svgid');
    box.width   = 640*scale;
    box.height  = 480*scale;
```

Hope this helps